# What are the default arguments in GPS's Build>Run command?

Tags: ada, gnat-gps

In [step 9 of the GPS tutorial](http://docs.adacore.com/gps-docs/tutorial/_build/html/run.html) I hit Build > Run and the "Run Main" dialog had filled in a bunch of command-line options like `builder%% -s blahblahblah %T`. Putting the argument "input.txt" at the end of that raised an exception, so I deleted it and replaced it with `%E input.txt`. Now the original options are gone and I can't use "Run Main" to run any project -- the "Run: sdc" window will open but nothing I type there produces a result.

Even when I uninstalled and reinstalled, GPS kept the same settings for this dialog. What arguments were originally present?

Alternate answer that would help: How can I get a fresh install that doesn't save my settings? I looked in the registry, AppData, and ProgramData folder for settings but didn't find this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GPS saves its information in %USERPROFILE%\.gps, so you could remove that directory. More specifically, I think it might be enough to remove targets.xml to reset the default switches here

Comment: I don't have a targets.xml, but I found the string in that directory in `histories.xml`. Here are the macros that were originally present: %builder -d %eL -P%PP %X %T . I can build again.